# How can I have a shell script copy back a file if there is a failure anywhere?

Tags: ruby, shell, rspec, bundle, bundler

At the beginning of the file I do

```
cp ~/.bundle/config  ~/.bundle/config_save
```

At the end of the file I restore it with

```
cp ~/.bundle/config_save ~/.bundle/config
```

and within the file I am issuing lots of different `rspec/spec/dir/file.rb` commands

How can I make it so that if interrupted by the user (<kbd>ctrl - c</kbd>), it does cleanup and restores the `config_save` file back to be `config` ?

I would like the processes to run in the foreground is possible so that I can see the actual failures themselves.  Failing this, perhaps another option might be to tail the logs/test.log in each repository.

Comment: Not sure if that's the best way:http://linuxcommand.org/wss0150.php, here sth about clean up functions http://linuxcommand.org/wss0160.php

Comment: *"...in which case the script craps out altogether"* why is that so?

Comment: Yeah, Stefan, updated to be about interrupt, not script failure.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I misunderstand your question, but can't you just "concatenate" the commands using `&&`:

```
cp ~/.bundle/config  ~/.bundle/config_save

rspec spec/dir/file1.rb &&
rspec spec/dir/file2.rb &&
rspec spec/dir/file3.rb

cp ~/.bundle/config_save ~/.bundle/config
```

If one of the `rspec` commands fails, the remaining commands are skipped and the next (i.e. last) line is executed.

Comment: +1, however, hmm, I may have over-simplified my version.  It is actually 3 pages long and having dozens `&&`s feels strange...

Comment: I also want it to alwyas run all but let me add that to the q